# Shift background-position vertically by a certain value?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a container with its background image *centered*:

```
<div class="foo"></div>

.foo {
   background: white url(../image.jpg) no-repeat scroll center center / cover;
}
```

Is there any way to shift the position of the background image vertically by a fixed value (e.g. 10px) relative to its original position either with pure CSS or  JS to get something like:

```
background-position: center (center - 10px);
```

Comment: background-position: 50% calc(50% - 10px);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `calc` CSS function in combination with `50%` value which means `center`:

```
background-position: center calc(50% - 10px);
```

Be careful, according to [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc) IE9 could have problems with that:

> Partial support in IE9 refers to the browser crashing when used as a
>   background-position value.

Another way is probably using `background-origin` property together with setting up the desired margin as a padding on the bottom (if you want to move the image up) or top (if you want to move the image down) of the box:

```
background-origin: content-box;
padding-bottom: 10px;
background-position: center center;
```

This looks uglier but at least should not have crashing problems with IE9.

Comment: (50% - 10px) maintain space otherwise it will not work.

Answer (score 6):

Try this [calc](https://css-tricks.com/a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc/)

```
.foo {
   background-position: 50% calc(50% - 10px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work well, can you elaborate more - what you are trying to achieve?

```
 background-position: center -10px;
```

This will move background image vertically 10px towards top